# Django - Starting a MQTT service in INIT prevents me from loading models with "Apps aren't loaded yet." error. Where can I start it?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm brand new to Django and Python, and not sure how to get around this problem, but I know what's wrong and why...

I'm connecting to a MQTT broker (internet of things messaging protocol / provider) so I can update a webpage with data from some sensors I have.

I've started the MQTT service in my init as was suggested below, but I don't know enough to know if that's right or wrong, but it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41017210/2408033

My problem happens, when I want to try to update my database with the messages I receive from the MQTT broker.  I need to import my model so I can update it, but the model hasn't been loaded yet, and it throws the error - "Apps aren't loaded yet."

I was reading that you shouldn't attempt to import models before the Django setup has run (which is after init) so I'm not sure where / how to start the loop for the MQTT broker thread?

Where else can I place the code to start the loop where it won't be triggered a second time?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the `ready` function of `apps.py` of your project. For example, in my `foo` app, I will have the following setup:

```
# code in __init__.py
default_app_config = 'foo.apps.MyFooConfig'

# code in apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyFooConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'Foo'

    def ready(self):
        from chat.mqtt import client
        client.loop_start()
```

More information can be read up [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#configuring-applications). Basically, this is introduced on Django 1.7 onwards.